# Wix Installer: Open file that starts with certain prefix (WixShellExecTarget)

Tags: properties, wix, installation

The released version number of the document is included in the filename and this is something that cannot be changed.  I want to open the release notes depending on the prefix, up to a certain point.  There will never be two different versions of the file in the same location, so you will never have "ReleaseNotes_v1.1.docx" and "ReleaseNotes_v1.2.docx" in the same directory.  But I don't want to hard code this either so the installation would have to be rebuilt with the version update.

Currently I have:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="ReleaseNotes_v1.1.docx" />
<CustomAction Id="ViewReleaseNotes" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

Which works as expected, but I would like to change it somehow so that I can just check "ReleaseNotes" and then grab the file that is there, so that if it has anything after the "Notes", it will still get it.

How can I do this?  Any help is appreciated as I am still pretty new to Wix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your release note file is installed as a key file in a `<Component...>` you could use a formatted property in the form of `[#ComponentId]` to refer to the full path of the installed file.

If a component with `Id="ComponentId"` is installed, the term `[#ComponentId]` evaluates to the full path of the key file of that component.

For information on formatted properties see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, this file is not being installed at all.  It will be on the DVD image and retrieved from there.